# How to load eclipse sdk in my Windows

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem loading eclipse sdk in my Windows PC. When I run eclipse.exe, 
there is a message flooded over the screen as: 
An error has occurred. See the log
file \Eclipse-SDK-4.2-win32\eclipse\configuratio\1348127323251.log

My OS- 32-Bit, Windows 7, 
Java 7, 
Eclipse SDK 4.2-win32 (Juno) also 32-Bit.

So please help me for it.

Comment: Surreal Log Lady quote from Twin Peaks: My log does not judge!

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your eclipse shortcut and go to Properties, in the Shortcut tab you can change what's in the Target: box to specify the jdk path

```
"C:\Program Files\eclipse-jee-galileo-sr1 (3.5.1)\eclipse.exe" -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin\javaw.exe"
```

[image]

Refer

http://www.matsim.org/node/372